Hypothesis testing for multiple univariate empirical distributions
Is there a way to assess if a single univariate empirical distribution is statistically different from a set of univariate empirical distributions, let's say 5? Something similar to ANOVA but for the entire distribution and that can allow me to tell which distribution is different from the others, and not if there is at least one distribution that is different from the others or if all the distributions are sampled from the same distribution (like Anderson-Darling k-Sample Test).
Maybe evaluating a distance matrix via Wasserstein distance and then something to check for a singleton?

Can you explain more clearly what you need? When you say if a single distribution is different than a set of distributions, it sounds like you want to compare a univariate distribution with multivariate distributions, which you cannot. If you want to compare one-against-one for all of them, then Anderson-Darling or K-S should suffice.

Yes, I meant one univariate distribution versus 5 other univariate distributions. I'm interested in one-versus-all test

Do you mean something like a many-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test instead of just a two-sample test?

@Dave yes but I'm interested in a one-vs-rest, like in post-hoc Tukey in ANOVA, for example

I am unsure if this is even possible to test at once. There's a variety of null hypotheses that will suffice to this, e.g., both $H_{0}: d_{i} = d_{j} = d_{j+1}$  and $H_{0}: d_{i} = d_{j} \neq d_{j+1}$. Since you are not interested in the similarity between $d_{j}$ and $d_{j+1}$, there's no unique way of specifying this, I think. My best bet would be to do pairwise K-S or A-D.

Ok, thank you for the time spent
